# How to redirect a user to the airflow homepage after authentication?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I am trying to use my own SSO for airflow web. After I authenticate and authorize a person, I am lost on how to redirect this authenticated user to the airflow homepage to access the dags. I found no direct code or understanding on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.
For more information, I'm writing a CustomAuthRemoteUserView which implements AuthOAuthView. This is where i authenticate the user and get his information in the form of a dict. But after this, I do not understand how to redirect the user the to the homepage of airflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/secure-apache-airflow-using-customer-security-manager/) website has really helped me understand how to go on with the custom security manager. I had to create the user manually in the db and then get the user to log them into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow implements its authentication capability with `flask_appbuilder.security.views.AuthOAuthView`.

You can access the `appbuilder` instance in your custom view and retrieve the index URL from it.

```py
from flask import redirect

#...
class CustomAuthRemoteUserView:

    def login(self, provider=None):
        #...
        index_url = self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index
        redirect(index_url)
        #...
```